# Amazon Linux AMI EC2 - librrd.so.2 dependency issue

Tags: python, linux, centos, cassandra, yum

I am attemping to install OpsCenter for Cassandra, and using the the standard REHL image.  I can't figure out how to get this to work.  Another version of EPEL perhaps?

yum install opscenter....
Error: Package: python26-rrdtool-1.2.27-1.i386 (opscenter)
           Requires: librrd.so.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI:

ftp://194.199.20.114/linux/EPEL/5/i386/rrdtool-1.2.27-3.el5.i386.rpm

Worked after rpm install and fixed dep issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing rrdtool via yum, that should contain librrd.so.2 and correct your issue.